# strncasecmp and strcasecmp has not been declared

Tags: c++, string-comparison, assimp

I'm trying to compile Assimp with MinGW in Code::Blocks, but I get the following errors.

```
\assimp-3.3.1\assimp-3.3.1\code\StringComparison.h||In function 'int Assimp::ASSIMP_stricmp(const char*, const char*)':|
\assimp-3.3.1\assimp-3.3.1\code\StringComparison.h|144|error: '::strcasecmp' has not been declared|
\assimp-3.3.1\assimp-3.3.1\code\StringComparison.h||In function 'int Assimp::ASSIMP_strincmp(const char*, const char*, unsigned int)':|
\assimp-3.3.1\assimp-3.3.1\code\StringComparison.h|193|error: '::strncasecmp' has not been declared|
```

While searching I've found out that the two functions in question (strcasecmp and strncasecmp) are in fact declared in `string.h` which is included in the header of `StringComparison.h`. I've also managed to get `strings.h`, the file which they originally belong to, but including that didn't solved the issue either.

While searching this site I've found out that I'm not the only one struggling with this issue. Another solution I've found suggested to use define statements, because the functions might have a slightly different name, but that didn't helped either.

Comment: They aren't in the standard C header `string.h`, because they aren't standard C functions.

Comment: Are you sure, you have included '#include <strings.h>' in your code.

Comment: You are probably looking at Msys headers that have these string functions. The mingw32 environment does not have these POSIX functions.

Comment: @juanchopanza I checked string.h and the functions are there.

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered this exact same problem, and this question came up during a Google search for the solution, so I'll document my dodgy solution here:

In the end I got it going just by making multiple small edits to the Assimp source code. Solving the string problem isn't enough to get it to work because it just fails later in the build. I'll list the edits I made below. I recommend making them one at a time and then rebuilding, just in case for whatever reason with your setup some of them aren't required. Note that you can't do model exporting with this solution because of the last edit (to Exporter.cpp) if you really need that you'll have to figure out another way to fix the link errors.

It's not a clean solution and it will probably be superceded by a future version of Assimp, at which point I will just delete it. This is for assimp-3.3.1, built with MinGW:

In StringComparison.h, edit the `ASSIMP_stricmp` function, commenting out everything except the `else` clause of the #ifdef:

```
/*#if (defined _MSC_VER)

    return ::_stricmp(s1,s2);
#elif defined( __GNUC__ )

    return ::strcasecmp(s1,s2);
#else*/
    char c1, c2;
    do  {
        c1 = tolower(*s1++);
        c2 = tolower(*s2++);
    }
    while ( c1 && (c1 == c2) );
    return c1 - c2;
//#endif
```

Do a similar thing in `ASSIMP_strincmp`.

Next, it throws up an error about `::_fullpath` in `DefaultIOSystem.cpp`. My "fix" for this was just to use comment out everything other the fallback option in this function:

```
    ai_assert(in && _out);
//    char* ret;
//#if defined( _MSC_VER ) || defined( __MINGW32__ )
//    ret = ::_fullpath( _out, in, PATHLIMIT );
//#else
    // use realpath
//    ret = realpath(in, _out);
//#endif
//    if(!ret) {
        // preserve the input path, maybe someone else is able to fix
        // the path before it is accessed (e.g. our file system filter)
//        DefaultLogger::get()->warn("Invalid path: "+std::string(in));
        strcpy(_out,in);
//    }
```

It also complains about snprintf being undefined. Edit `StringUtils.h` to change the following #define to add an underscore before snprintf:

```
#   define ai_snprintf _snprintf
```

There's also an error about ::atof not being defined. You can fix this by adding

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

to StringUtils.h

This should get it building but there will be a link error in `Exporter.cpp` (this might be due to my specific CMake setttings because I disabled almost all model formats). I fixed it by commenting out the definition of `gExporters` and replacing it with this:

```
Exporter::ExportFormatEntry* gExporters = 0;
```

After this it built and ran fine. The library files are placed in the `code` folder. Place libassimp.dll.a in your lib build path and libassimp.dll in the path of your executable.

Of course, you can also get it going by using VisualStudio instead (I didn't because I couldn't be bothered installing it) or by building on Linux (I did this previously and it built fine first go, but I needed to do a Windows port).

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems too but hopefully I was able to solve them. I know this is probably too late to help in particular but I hope someone on the Internet will find this useful. I compile using Code::Blocks 16.01 using gcc 5.3.0.

**::strncasecmp not declared in this scope:**

You have to include  and remove the "::"

**::_fullpath not declared in this scope:**

I never had to perform the operation of finding a full path, so this one is the one I am the least sure of. But anyway, since I couldn't simply remove everything, I had to find the alternative. That is, using "GetFullPathName".
So, as suggested by MSDN, I included , , , . 
I also replace the line :
`ret = _fullpath( _out, in, PATHLIMIT );` 
by 
`ret = (char*)GetFullPathName(in, PATHLIMIT, _out, NULL);`

Should work fine, full path is obtained and error checking is kept too.

**vsnprintf not declared in this scope**

Just add an underscore `_` in front of the function name.

**to_string is not a member of std::**

I would have that this is the usual bug from using MinGW, but actually, Assimp contains a built-in alternative to `std::to_string`. You just have to remove the `std::` part and it should roll.
Make sure to include  in the files in which just removing `std::` doesn't work.

**`test\CMakeFiles\gtest.dir\build.make|109|recipe for target 'test/gtest/src/gtest-stamp/gtest-build' failed|` ?**

It doesn't matter, you already have your working .dll in the "code" folder ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was using Cygwin and encounter the same error, using strncmp and strcmp worked, guessing it is something to do with the libraries (ANSI C++) currently implemented for Cygwin or being used by your project. Not sure though, just wanted it to work for the moment...